# How to provide placeholder awaitable interface method implementations?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

Prior to all this `await`/`async` stuff, you'd have an interface like:

```
public interface ITest
{
    bool Method();
}
```

If you created a `public class Test : ITest{}` then Visual Studio would give you the intellisense option to implement the interface, leading to:

```
public class Test : ITest
{
    public bool Method()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But now we do a lot of `async` stuff so our interface and generated code looks like:

```
public interface ITest
{
    Task<bool> MethodAsync();
}

public class Test : ITest
{
    public Task<bool> MethodAsync()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Except**, this method isn't marked `async` - you cannot mark interface methods `async` and VS doesn't intuit it from the method name/signature. So we add that to the method and now the compiler isn't happy:
[image]

It's quite common to auto-implement an interface and then work to properly implement each method but it seems now we have to fix all the generated methods which reduces the usefulness.

Is there a solution/workaround? What *should* the placeholder method actually look like?

Comment: *"**Except**, this method isn't implemented `async`"* - That's perfectly fine. Leave the `async` keyword off until you write code in it that uses `await`.

Comment: `Task<T>` is awaitable by itself.

Comment: @madreflection that's an interesting thought I hadn't considered. Is that something you've seen done often? It feels 'dirty' to have `MethodAsync` not marked `async` somehow

Comment: `async` is not part of the method definition in IL at all. If you don't need C# to transform your method into a coroutine, then you don't need it.

Comment: `async` is a hint to the compiler to implement the method a certain way. "Being awaitable" is not a property of actual code, that's solely the result of it returning `Task` (or more generally an awaitable type).

Comment: Agree with @madreflection You can see this done in the ASP.net core source code, mostly in mocked test objects

Comment: You'll notice in the parameter help that it says "(awaitable)" regardless of whether the method has `async` on it.  The fact that it's awaitable is what matters. I took some flack for this a while back, but I still opine that they should be called "awaitable methods" not "async methods" if they return `Task`/`Task<T>`. A truly "async method" is one that's been transformed, which the caller shouldn't care about because that's an implementation detail.

Comment: @madreflection `Task` predates the `await` keyword, and represents an asynchronous operation, thus a method returning a `Task` should be considered asynchronous. The `Task` type can clearly be abused, but that shouldn't affect the naming. The `async` keyword also isn't the only way to create a "truly asynchronous" method; consider `TaskCompletionSource` for example.

Comment: @madreflection I also prefer that distinction. I've used "asynchronous" in the past, but "awaitable" is more distinct.